# How can I select records (containing Dates) grouped by Week

Tags: c#, sql-server, group-by

I have a table containing a field of dates + a field named WeekDayID (sun=0, mon=1, tue=2, wed=3, thu=4, fri=5, sat=6) + some other field (not important to mention), and I need two reports:
1.based on month
2.based on week

I have done the report number 1

my question is HOW CAN I ACHIEVE report 2, I need something that gives me this:

---

let's say we have dates from 2001/01/01 to 2001/01/31

I want to get all days grouped by week for example if 2001/01/01 is Sunday i want groups like:

1st week : 2001/01/01 - 2001/01/02 - ... - 2001/01/07
2nd week : 2001/01/08 - ... - 2001/01/14
3rd week : 2001/01/15 - ... - 2001/01/21
4th week : 2001/01/22 - ... - 2001/01/28
5th week : 2001/01/29 - 2001/01/30 - 2001/01/31

Comment: I hope this will helps you http://doddlereport.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20your%20first%20report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the week number you can use the Datepart function with the value 'ww' for the first parameter:

```
SELECT Datepart(ww, myDate) FROM myTable
```

For the date range, you can do some math tricks: Substract to your date the weekday to get the first day of the week:

```
SELECT DateAdd(day, - DatePart(weekday, myDate), myDate) Week_Start
from myTable
```

here you have a link to the DatePart function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174420.aspx